# Trying to determine if the user is logged in and display name

Tags: asp.net, aspdotnetstorefront

If the user it logged in, it should display `welcome, [name]`, otherwise display the `register link`.

Using `aspdotnet` storefront - the following displays both `welcome,` (without the logged in name) and also shows the `register link`? Can't seem to get it working properly.

```
<xsl:when test="/root/System/CustomerFirstName!=''">
                            Welcome, <a href='/account.aspx'><xsl:value-of select="/root/System/CustomerFirstName" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></a>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                            <a href='createaccount.aspx?checkout=False' class='register'>
                            Register </a>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
```

I've even followed page 30 on [here](http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/pdf/XmlPackages2.1.pdf) but to no avail.

Comment: Can you please specify what version of AspDotNetStorefront you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking the CustomerIsRegistered node instead, to determine if the user is currently signed in and registered. The value will either be 'true' or 'false'.

Here is a working example:

```
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="/root/System/CustomerIsRegistered='true'">
        <!--Customer is registered-->
        <a href="account.aspx">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Welcome, ',/root/System/CustomerFirstName)"/>
        </a>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--Customer is not registered-->
        <a href="createaccount.aspx">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">register</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:text>Register</xsl:text>              
        </a>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

If you prefer to check CustomerFirstName then I would suggest testing if the string length is greater than 0. For example:

`<xsl:when test="string-length(/root/System/CustomerFirstName) &gt; 0>`

Like Michael stated, make sure your Choose element is properly formatted. You should receive an error when trying to run the Xml Package if your xslt markup is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should have it. Make sure you have it surrounded by a choose node.

```
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/root/System/CustomerFirstName!=''">
              Welcome, <a href='/account.aspx'>
                <xsl:value-of select="/root/System/CustomerFirstName" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
              </a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <a href='createaccount.aspx?checkout=False' class='register'>
                Register
              </a>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
```

Try placing it just after the start of

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

and turn on debug mode at the top to help with testing.